# AsyncStorage.getItem returning undefined when using fetch - React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, fetch, asyncstorage

I'm trying to set a token in my SignIn component using a promise and AsyncStorage but when I go to retrieve the token for use in a different component I get the error `Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined`. I tried using Async/Await to wait for the token response in order to save it to storage but i've been getting the same error. How can I properly set the token?

SignIn.js Component

```
//Function is bound
async signIn() {
const data = JSON.stringify({username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password})

  await fetch(`https://somesecretdomain.com:8443/users/login`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: data
}).then((response) => response.json()).then(async(responseJson) => { 
  AsyncStorage.setItem('jwt', responseJson.id_token);

  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Profile'})]
  });
  this
    .props
    .navigation
    .dispatch(resetAction);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.warn(error);
})
};
```

Profile.js Component

```
async fetchData() {
AsyncStorage
  .getItem('jwt')
  .then((value) => {
    this.setState({"TOKEN": value});
  })
  .done();

console.log(this.state.TOKEN)
const response = await 
fetch(`https://somesecretdomain.com:8443/users/getUsers`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'token': this.state.TOKEN
  }
})
const json = await response.json()
```

}

I changed the Profile.js component to below, still getting the same error.

```
import React, {AsyncStorage, localStorage} from 'react';
import {
Text,
View,
Image,
TouchableHighlight,
WebView,
TextInput,
KeyboardAvoidingView,
ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

 async fetchData() {
 const TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt');
 const response = await 
 fetch(`https://somedomain.com:8443/users/getUsers`, {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'token' : TOKEN
},
});
const result = await response.json();
  this.setState({data: result})
}
```

Comment: Why are you using fetch and await together? await resolves the promise and returns the result. You should be doing something like const response = await fetch(...); const result = await response.json(); await AsyncStorage.setItem(..., result.id_token)

Comment: The way you are doing it, you aren't actually awaiting the result of all the promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
async signIn() {
    const data = JSON.stringify({username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password})

  const response = await fetch(`https://somesecretdomain.com:8443/users/login`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: data
  });
  const result = await response.json();
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('jwt', result.id_token);

  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Profile'})]
  });
  this
    .props
    .navigation
    .dispatch(resetAction);
});
};
```

Comment: hmm....getting the same error `cannot read property getItem of defined`

Comment: I edited the the Profile component to the below, but still unable to get the value.


    `async fetchData() {
    const TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt');
    const response = await 
    fetch(`https://somedomain.com:8443/users/getUsers`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'token' : TOKEN
  },
   });
  const result = await response.json();

      this.setState({data: result})


    }`

Comment: are you awaiting the call to signin?

Comment: If the error is 'cannot read property getItem of undefined' then you aren't importing AsyncStorage right.

Comment: This is how I have it imported `import React, {AsyncStorage, localStorage} from 'react';`

Comment: It's in react-native, not react

Comment: You were spot on. changing the AsyncStorage to import from React-Native instead of react fixed the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: This works as well as importing from react-native is deprecated. 
`import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";`